# JavaScript - generating data and refreshing in intervals

Tags: javascript, leaflet, setinterval

I am working on project in JavaScript. I am building interactive map in Leaflet, on which i will visualize data. 
Currently there is no real data to be visualized, I just need to demostrate how it should be working. 
I am visualizing data with Data Visualization Framework for Leaflet. Value is shown by Radial meter marker. I am currently generating data into marker with function *Math.random()*.
How it looks on the map:
[Radial meter marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6ca7.png)

**How my code looks like:**

```
    //here are my data
    geojsondata = {
     "type": "FeatureCollection",
     "features": [{
       "type": "Feature",
       "properties": {
         "name": "1",
         "value": Math.random() * 200
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [315, -360]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "2",
        "value": Math.random() * 200

      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [360, -360]
       }
      }
     ]
    }


    //here I am adding markers to map
    var marker = new L.geoJSON(geojsondata, {
     pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
      return new L.RadialMeterMarker(latlng, {
       data: {
        'Value': feature.properties.value
       },
      chartOptions: {
        'Value': {
          displayName: 'Value',
          displayText: function (value) {
            return value.toFixed(1);
          },
          color: 'hsl(240,100%,55%)',
          fillColor: 'hsl(240,80%,55%)',
          maxValue: 200,
          minValue: 0
        }
      },
      displayOptions: {
        'Value': {
          color: new L.HSLHueFunction(new L.Point(0,minHue), new L.Point(200,maxHue), {outputSaturation: '100%', outputLuminosity: '25%'}),
          fillColor: new L.HSLHueFunction(new L.Point(0,minHue), new L.Point(200,maxHue), {outputSaturation: '100%', outputLuminosity: '50%'})
        }
      },
      fillOpacity: 0.8,
      opacity: 1,
      weight: 0.5,
      radius: 20,
      barThickness: 15,
      maxDegrees: 360,
      rotation: 0,
      numSegments: 10
        });
      },
    });
    marker.addTo(map);
```

**What I need to do:**
I need to generate value in time intervals (for example 5 seconds) and at same time refresh the map, so I can see new value in map marker.

**What I tried:**

1. I tried to create function with setInterval: 
   [Data are generated, but value in marker is 0](https://playcode.io/311530?tabs=console&script.js)
2. I tried to put whole geojsondata into function with setInterval and also create markers with setInterval function.:
   [Data are generated, markers are refreshing, but they are stacking](https://playcode.io/311535?tabs=console&script.js)

I think that I am close to what i need in my second code. But i dont know how to remove previous marker to prevent them to stack on the top of each other. Can anyone help me out with this? Thank you.

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon at the end of `geojsondata = { ...`
https://playcode.io/311560?tabs=console&script.js&output

Comment: do you want to clear EVERY marker at the start of the interval? 
check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256026/clear-marker-layers-leaflet), as it may be what you want

Comment: @JacobThomas Thank you man! I find out how to do it thanks to that link!

Comment: I'm going to post that as an answer, since it was what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the markers, you need to keep a reference to them or the layer.

[Clear Marker Layers (Leaflet )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256026/clear-marker-layers-leaflet)
this is a good example on making a layer layer that allows you to easily remove the markers for later.
[docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#layergroup)