# Remove all the markers in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a map with different markers and I need to delete it and show others. For this objective I'm using `clearLayers()` (my script is based using the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256026/clear-marker-layers-leaflet)).

Below I add my code. What I'm trying to do, is knowing if I have markers in my map and if the answer is yes, delete it and show the new ones. But `layerGroup` is always `undefined`... How can I delete it? I'm doing correctly the `layerGroup`?

```
function markersMap(coords){
    // Delete previous markers
    if (layerGroup === undefined) {
        console.log('layerGroup undefined');
    } else{
        console.log('layerGroup defined');
        layerGroup.clearLayers();
    }        
    // markers
    var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map); 
    var marker = "L.marker(coo,{icon: iconMarker}).bindPopup(popUp).addTo(layerGroup);";

    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
        popUp = String(coords[i][0]);
        coo = [coords[i][1],coords[i][2]];
        if (coords[i][3] <= 3) {
            var colorMarker = "red.png";
        } else if (coords[i][3] == 4) {
            var colorMarker = "orange.png";
        } else {
            var colorMarker = "green.png";
        }
        var iconMarker = new L.Icon({
            iconUrl: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-'+colorMarker,
            iconSize: [25, 41],
            iconAnchor: [12, 41],
            popupAnchor: [1, -34],
            shadowSize: [41, 41]
        });
        eval("marker" + i + "=" + marker);        
    }    
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This layer group will always give you undefined, because you declared it after checking the condition.

You may declare layer group outside of the function, and use [map.hasLayer()](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-haslayer) to check it.

Here is the example:

```
var layerGroup = L.layerGroup();

function markersMap (coords) {

    // Check is map already has this layer group
    if (map.hasLayer(layerGroup)) {

        // Clear layer group
        layerGroup.clearLayers();

        // Or you may remove entire layer from the map
        // This will help you reduce rendering issues
        map.removeLayer(layerGroup);
    }

    // Do something ... (e.g., adding new marker to layer group)
    // Then add layer group to current map
    map.addLayer(layerGroup);
}
```

Full example:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([40.7128, -74.0060], 7);
var layerGroup = L.layerGroup();

var googleTile = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
   maxZoom: 20,
   subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3'],
   attribution: ''
}).addTo(map);

function markersMap (coords) {
  if (map.hasLayer(layerGroup)) {
    console.log('already have one, clear it');
    layerGroup.clearLayers();
  } else {
    console.log('never have it before');
  }
  
  var marker = L.marker(coords);
  layerGroup.addLayer(marker);
  map.addLayer(layerGroup);
}

// Check by calling the function 2 times.
markersMap([40.7128, -74.0060]);
markersMap([40.1234567, -74.0060]);
```

```css
#map { width: 100%; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map">
```

Comment: Where I have to write `var layerGroup = L.layerGroup();`? Because I put a `console.log()` inside the `if` and it never pass inside it. It is not crashing but it is not deleting the markers too. Or maybe my mistake now is with the `map.addLayer()`. Thank you

Comment: It never pass inside it, because it can't find your `layerGroup` variable. You can put it above or outside of the function. For example, put it under your `var map = L.map()`. Hope it helps.

Comment: I did it but is not working... I think maybe I am doing wrong `layergroup` adding the markers

Comment: I added the full example :)

Comment: first of all thank you for spend your time with my problem. But your proposal is not working, see I modified the second input of coords and is not deleting the first one. There are 2 markers :(

Comment: My bad, If we change it to layerGroup.clearLayers(), it will solve this problem.