# Unable to remove all markers from map leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm learning Leaflet, currently I'm stuck on a situation that I can't solve. My problem is that I was unable to remove the markers from the MAP. After some research I came across three methods of doing this (marker.remove(), removeLayer and clearleyars). but none of them solved my problem (that of removing all the markers before loading the others). With marker.remove() set on the click event of a button, I manage to remove the markers but not all of them. There is 1 marker left that duplicates...

```
var map = L.map("map").setView([-1.54862, 21.86789], 6);
var condition = null;
L.tileLayer("https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  maxZoom: 90,
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
}).addTo(map);

////////////////////////////////////////////////MAP-DATA///////////////////////////////////////
var marker = L.marker();
function MapData(result) {
  $.each(result, function (index, element) {
    var pop = L.popup({
      closeOnClick: true,
    }).setContent(
      '<img src="' +
        element.Photo +
        '"> <br>ESECOPE : <b> ' +
        element.ESECOPE +
        " </b> <br> Etablissement :  <b>  " +
        element.LIB_ETAB +
        "  </b>  <br>Antenne :  <b>  " +
        element.ANTENNE +
        "  </b>  <br> Province Educationnelle :  <b>  " +
        element.DirectionProv +
        "  </b> <br> <button> Voir la Carte Scolaire </button> "
    );

    var Position = new L.LatLng(element.lat, element.lng);
    marker = L.marker(Position).addTo(map).bindPopup(pop);

    marker.addTo(map);
    map.setView(Position, 6);
  });
}

$("#nextBtn").on("click", function () {
  marker.remove();
  var ProvEd = document.getElementById("ProvEd").value;
  var Antenne = document.getElementById("Antenne").value;

  $.ajax({
    url: "js/ajax/ajax/ProcessMapQuery.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      Prov_data: ProvEd,
      Ant_data: Antenne,
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
      document.querySelector(".dropleft").classList.toggle("active");

      MapData(result);
    },
  });
});
```

Remove markers from map leaflet before loading others

Comment: Seems like running `clearLayers` on layer group does work, have you looked into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051624/remove-all-the-markers-in-leaflet

Comment: Another solution might be to add each marker to an array when you create it. You can then iterate over the array to add them all to the map, and iterate again to remove them all from the map.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add layer group to your map, and then add markers not to the map directly, but to the layergroup.

```
var marker = L.marker();
var markers = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);
function MapData(result) {
    $.each(result, function(index, element) { 
        var pop = L.popup({    
            closeOnClick: true
        }).setContent('<img src="'+ element.Photo + '"> <br>ESECOPE : <b> '+ element.ESECOPE + ' </b> <br> Etablissement :  <b>  '+ element.LIB_ETAB + '  </b>  <br>Antenne :  <b>  '+ element.ANTENNE + '  </b>  <br> Province Educationnelle :  <b>  '+element.DirectionProv+'  </b> <br> <button> Voir la Carte Scolaire </button> ');
  
        var Position = new L.LatLng(element.lat, element.lng);            
        marker = L.marker(Position).addTo(map).bindPopup(pop);

        marker.addTo(markers);
        map.setView(Position,6);                   
  })           
}

$('#nextBtn').on('click', function() {
    markers.clearLayers();
    //your code below
}
```