# Does Turf.js allow polygon-to-polygon spatial join?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, gis, turfjs

Does Turf.js support spatial joins between polygons and polygons?
I have a task with a clickable leaflet.js city map that highlights the closest building polygons within a radius from any clicked-upon road.

The task finds the closest road segment (geojson line object) to the coordinates clicked, adds it to the leaflet.js map, and then draws a Turf.js buffer polygon, and adds it to the leaflet.js map too.

Next is spatially joining the buffer with the building polygons to get the buildings within the buffer.

But no function seems to exist for that. Instead, I have to for-loop through every building polygon, do turf.booleanContains() + turf.booleanOverlap(), and add the passing polygons to the map.

This is probably fine, but this for-loop stuff is too costly because I have 900K building polygons to iterate thru for every single click I do. Well, I have to do that to find the closest road segments too, but old idea was buffering a circle around the clicked coordinates, spatially joining the road-segments within it and THEN iterating within those road segments only, ... until I couldn't find out any polygon-to-polyline spatial join either in Turf.js.

My next option is doing all of this stuff behind the curtain with python geopandas.

```
      <script>
         // Creating map options
var mapOptions = {
            center: [40.7128, -74.0060],
            zoom: 10,
            zoomControl: false
}
         
// Create Map
var map = new L.map('map', mapOptions); // Creating a map object
// Creating Layer
var layer = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');         
map.addLayer(layer);   // Adding layer to the map

      
// zoom control options         
var zoomOptions = {
            zoomInText: '1',
            zoomOutText: '0',
         
};
var zoom = L.control.zoom(zoomOptions);   // Creating zoom control         
zoom.addTo(map);   // Adding zoom control to the map
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256026/clear-marker-layers-leaflet


var streetSegments = // list of street segment geojson line objects
var parcelLots = // list of building footprint geojson polygon objects

// Adding the layers group to add the geojson layers
var mapLayerGroup;
mapLayerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

var streetSegmentLayer;
var streetSegmentBufferLayer; 
var parcelLotLayer; 

streetSegmentLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(mapLayerGroup ); 
// a currently blank layer that street segment polylines will be added onto later
streetSegmentBufferLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(mapLayerGroup ); 
// a currently blank layer that street segments buffer polygons will be added onto later
parcelLotLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(mapLayerGroup ); 
// a currently blank layer that building footprint polygons will be added onto later

map.on('click', 
function(e)
{

// clear the map's canvas and re-add the geojson layers again
// this allows us to auto-delete (and "refresh") all the old highlighted street segment, polygons, and buffers when a new coordinate is clicked.
mapLayerGroup.clearLayers(); 
streetSegmentLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(mapLayerGroup ); 
streetSegmentBufferLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(mapLayerGroup );
parcelLotLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(mapLayerGroup ); 

// get the latlng and then x/y coords of the clicked location
var selectedCoords = e.latlng.toString().split(',');
var lat = selectedCoords[0].split('(')[1];
var lng = selectedCoords[1].split(')')[0];
            
document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
document.getElementById('lon').value = lng;

var turfCoords = turf.point([lng, lat]);

console.log("You clicked the map at latitude: " + lat + " and longitude:" + lng);

// project the coordinates that were clicked on to Mercator
var projectedCoords = turf.toMercator(turfCoords);

// Find the closest Street Segment to the selected (and then projected) coordinates
var tempStreetSegment = streetSegments[0];
var tempStreetSegmentDistance = turf.pointToLineDistance(projectedCoords, tempStreetSegment, {units: 'feet'});
var closestStreetSegment = tempStreetSegment; 
var closestStreetSegmentDistance = tempStreetSegmentDistance;
for (let i = 1; i < streetSegments.length; i++) {
    tempStreetSegment =  streetSegments[i];
    tempStreetSegmentDistance = turf.pointToLineDistance(projectedCoords, tempStreetSegment, {units: 'feet'});
    if (tempStreetSegmentDistance < closestStreetSegmentDistance) {
        closestStreetSegment = tempStreetSegment;
        closestStreetSegmentDistance = tempStreetSegmentDistance;
    } else {
    }
}


// Shows the closest street segment polyline to the chosen coordinate  visibly on the map
var currStreetSegment = turf.toWgs84(closestStreetSegment)  // never forget to re-project
streetSegmentLayer.addData(currStreetSegment)

// Shows the buffer around the current street segment polyline visibly on the map
var streetSegmentBuffer = turf.buffer(currStreetSegment.toGeoJSON(), 500, {units: "feet"})
var currStreetSegmentBuffer = turf.toWgs84(streetSegmentBuffer) // never forget to re-project
streetSegmentBufferLayer.addData(currStreetSegmentBuffer);

// Show the parcel lots that fall within the buffer
var tempParcelLot;
var currParcelLot;
//var parcelLotsWithinBuffer = [];
for (let i = 1; i < parcelLots.length; i++) {
    tempParcelLot =  parcelLots[i]; // a building footprint polygon
    if (turf.booleanContains(streetSegmentBuffer, tempParcelLot) || turf.booleanOverlap(streetSegmentBuffer, tempParcelLot)) {
        //parcelLotsWithinBuffer.push(tempParcelLot);
        currParcelLot = turf.toWgs84(tempParcelLot);
        parcelLotLayer.addData(currParcelLot)
    } else {
    }
}


});

      </script>
```